# How to create a zoom invariant 1px line with HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, zooming

I want to make a 1px or 2px wide (pixel-perfect) line in HTML/CSS that does not change in thickness when zooming the page in or out.

I like to make web-applications work well with different zoom levels (I zoom in on websites all the time and have all websites zoomed in to at least 120%). I am now building something with a custom editor that has a cursor which is an HTML element. When I zoom in the cursor thickness varies depending on its location (the browser rounds everything to whole pixels), and I want to figure out a way to make it constant thickness and preferably zoom invariant as well. Of course I would prefer not involving JavaScript but so far I have not found any suggestions on how to implement this. The one method I can think of is using an HTML canvas that is scaled using the devicePixelRatio (and re-rendered whenever the user zooms). If you have tried to implement something similar or have alternative suggestions, I would love to hear about it!

Comment: To make a 1px border, use `border: .1px solid red;`. This works in Chrome/Firefox, though not Edge.